# Combine multiple object mapper strings in java

Tags: java, object, request, entity, objectmapper

I want to use the object mapper class in java to pick certain parts of an api request object to use in another request.

```
Request: {"access_instrument":{"id":"12345","additional_attributes":[1123],"instrument_lifecycle_reasons":[4423],"associated_instruments":[123],"links":[]},"types":[],"states":[],"metadata":[]}
```

I currently have:

```
ObjectMapper obMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    obMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    String requestStr1 = obMapper.writeValueAsString(searchCriteria.getAccessInstrument().getId());
    String requestStr2 = obMapper.writeValueAsString(searchCriteria.getAccessInstrument().getInstrumentLifecycleReasons());
    String requestStr3 = obMapper.writeValueAsString(searchCriteria.getAccessInstrument().getAssociatedInstruments());
    Entity<String> requestEntity = Entity.entity(requestStr1+requestStr2+requestStr3, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
```

However I feel this will run into issues with the api validations due to formatting, and adding spacing manually, doesn't seem efficient. Is there a way I can pick apart the data I want from the request body to then send it in the new request?

Note: the requestEntity variable is the request payload that is used in the api call

Comment: What kind of object is the **searchCriteria**? Because I don't see you adding any spaces and also you can use StringBuilder to add all the values as a single string.

Comment: Instead of using `String` can't you just create a new class with the fields from `searchCriteria` of interest?

Comment: If you concatenate multiple JSON strings together, what you get isn't valid JSON. In this case, it would be `"12345"[4423][123]`. Adding spacing won't make it valid, either (whitespace is not significant in JSON). I agree with @D-Dᴙum that you would be better off modelling the data for the other request with a new class.